# Moving patches in git repository with different directory structure

Tags: git

I'm sorry for the somewhat verbose and confused title. We have a git repository with the following directory structure (the root represents the repository root; the names are fictional):

```
/
/dir1/
/dir2/
/dir2/subdir1/
/dir2/subdir2/
```

A team colleague created a new git repository with a copy of `/dir2/subdir1`, i.e. the `/dir2/subdir1` became the root of the new repository. We did some (~15) commits in that new repository, then we decided that we would like to replicate the new commits in the old repository.

What is the best way to perform this action?

Of course we could create a patch from the new repository and apply it as single commit in the old one, but we would lose granularity of history by doing so.

There have been no commits in the old repository in the meantime that touched `/dir2/subdir1`, so there should definitely be no conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use [`git format-patch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) and [`git am`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-am). In the new repository I did a

```
git format-patch $revision
```

, where `$revision` is the revision in the new repository which corresponds to the status of the old repository, i.e. the revision where `/dir2/subdir1` was added. This created around 15 files containing the patches of every single commit.

Then I moved to the old repository and used `git am` to apply the patches just created. I just had to specify the directory where these patches had to be applied:

```
git am --directory dir2/subdir1 $patches
```

, where `$patches` are the files created during the previous step.

Now the commits are moved from the new repo into the old one and I'm happy!

Answer (score -2):

**Option1**: Create patch of each commit separately (`git format-patch`), and apply in order to the old repo

**Option2**: Add the new repo as remote to old one, fetch the branch, Checkout the branch on your local repo and cherry-pick all commits (With `gitk` it is even easier`)

**Option3**:Add the new repo as remote to old one, fetch the branch, and merge it with the branch in old repo.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Option1 is clear. I would like to avoid it because it is time-expensive and boring, and because I would like to learn something new in git (if possible). Options 2 and 3 rely on the fact that both repositories are compatible in terms of directory structure, don't they? If I merge the branch in the new repo with the branch in the old one I lose the directories `/dir1/` and `/dir2/subdir2/`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Spiros: No, you wont lose anything unless you have explicitly deleted them in your new repository and committed the delete.


The directory structure needs to be same: Yes and No! If in your old repo you have /dir2/sub1 and in the new repo also you have /dir2/sub1 it will be no difference. But if in your new repo you have only /sub1, then you are in a bit of a problem! :) (Solvable though)

Comment: My situation is that `/dir2/subdir1` is the root of the new repository: all files in that directory are in the root of the new repo. Anyway, your suggestion with Option1 was really successful, I solved my problem with just two commands. I will post an answer to my own question. Thanks a lot!