# Applying a git patch when repository directory structures differ

Tags: git, patch, subdirectory

I was e-mailed a git patch on "code1" created with format-patch.  Problem is that the co-worker who sent it apparently has a different directory structure than I have.  My directory looks like

```
/home
   /mydir
     /project
        /code1
           /src
           /obj
           /bin
        /code2
        /code3
```

and my .git is sitting in /project.  He apparently only has /code1 and that's where his .git is sitting.  However, his `/code1` does look exactly like my `/code1`.

I try to apply the patch with git am, and it fails with the error

```
error: src/foo.c: does not exist in index
error: src/bar.c: does not exist in index
Patch failed at <new commit message>.
```

I have tried using the --directory flag, but I get the same error, only with the directory names changed.  Is there any way to do this.

BTW, I anticipate someone is going to flag this as a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715530/moving-patches-in-git-repository-with-different-directory-structure), but the situation there was somewhat different and the solution given there has not helped me.  Thanks.

Comment: Read the link and hope it helps.
[https://blog.soltysiak.it/en/2017/08/how-to-use-git-patch-system-to-apply-changes-into-another-folder-structure/](https://blog.soltysiak.it/en/2017/08/how-to-use-git-patch-system-to-apply-changes-into-another-folder-structure/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git am` is designed to *re-create the original commit* from the patch.

To re-create the original commit (with the same hash ID and everything), the change made in *your* repository must be bit-for-bit identical to the change made in *his* repository. This would naturally require that your repository have the same layout (and parent commits leading to this point) as those in the patch.

Since your repository has a different structure, you cannot use `git am` to apply the patch.  You can instead use `git apply`, but you will have to fuss with the path names a bit.  Note that, like the standard *patch* utility, the `-p number` option lets you remove path components, but that won't help in this case.  In this case, you will need to *add* some path components, so you want the `--directory=path` option.